# comparison in shell script with division always giving false

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a very simple comparison in shell bash script, but I never get it correct:

count=0

```
if [ expr $count / 4 = 0 ];
then
  echo "yes";
else
  echo "no";
fi
```

always giving no?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to do here? Checking if $count / 4 == 0 will only tell you if $count is less than 4. Why not use `if [ $count -lt 4 ]`?

Comment: I am writing some thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918098/string-concatenation-in-bash-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to call out to the expr program, you have to actually call out to it:

```
if [ $(expr $count / 4) = 0 ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

However, bash can do it in-house:

```
if (( $count / 4 == 0 )); then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that bash could do that. EDIT: It took a little while, but I found a guide. Thanks for teaching me a new trick. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html

Comment: Actually, with `(())` you don't even need the `$`. This would do: `if (( count / 4 == 0 )); then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) (`$()` or backticks) to evaluate the `eval` expression. Also, use `-eq` for [integer comparison](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html):

```
if [ $(expr $count / 4) -eq 0 ];
then
  echo "yes";
else
  echo "no";
fi
```

Comment: For integers you can use `-eq` or `==` since string equivalence and integer equivalence are the same.

Comment: Yes, the `==` string comparison would usually work, but if the if statement was written as `if [ $(expr $count / 4) == 00 ]` then it would give an unintended result. Best to use the comparison operator that is intended for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
[[ count/4 -eq 0 ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```